# Shiny : how to show that a graph is deprecated

Tags: r, shiny

I have a reactive plot (renderPlot) in Shiny that is dependent of a very large number of user inputs and need extensive computation. I isolated the graph using:

```
output$myGraph <- renderPlot({
  input$goButton
  isolate({
    myFunction(input$var1, .... input$varn)
  })
})
```

Nevertheless, I would like to provide an indication to the user, as soon as he changes a single input, that the current graph is **not up to date**. 
Any idea on how to do that without checking all the inputs?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you create another output variable in the Shiny Server that shows an image (or whatever) once your graph is deprecated. To make that indicator show at the right time you create a reactive value (a value you make yourself and works like an input$ variable) that gets the deprecation flag depending on all the input changes. Once you plot the graph you reset the deprecation flag.

```
# Only called when applications starts
values <- reactiveValues()
values$deprecated <- -1 

# Function that depends on all input variables and sets deprecation flag
computeDeprecation <- reactive({ 
    input$...
    ...
    input$...
    #activate deprecation
    values$deprecated <- 1 


})

# function that depends on deprecationflag (only if it changes, not everytime
# computeDeprecation() is called) and outputs and deprecation indicator
output$indication<- renderImage({
    if(values$deprecated != 1){
        return()
    }
    #show deprecation indicator
})

output$myGraph <- renderPlot({
  input$goButton
  isolate({
     myFunction(input$var1, .... input$varn)
     # reset deprecated variable
     values$deprecated <- 1
  })
})
```